# How to obfuscate data in windows registry - security manager?

Tags: windows, security, registry

I heard there was a way to hide registry keys in windows but can't remember what it is - it may have related to a security manager.

What I would like to do is prevent a user from copying my software activation keys from the registry, deactivating the software, then reactivating it by copying the old keys back into place.

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault or possibly superuser.

Comment: Can't he just reinstall anyway?

Comment: No.  Bear in mind I haven't described the licensing scheme in detail, that's another topic!  I'd just like a way to hide keys in the registry so they can't be easily restored if my software chooses to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution for this that i know is to use a GPO, which is saved in a protected part of the registery

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't hide anything from the user (assuming they are an administrator), but you can make it more difficult.

You can "hide" registry keys using the native API to access the registry, versus the Win32 API. This effectively means that the user won't be able to delete or recreate the registry keys using RegEdit. They would have to resort to using the native API as well.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14508/Registry-Manipulation-Using-NT-Native-APIs) describes the native API, as well as hidden registry keys (which use embedded nulls in the key names). The [RegHide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd581628) tool by Sysinternals allows you to hide registry keys, and the [RegDelNull](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897448) tool allows you to delete them.

But again, a resourceful person can still get around this. The only way to ensure that it is still valid is to have a third-party (such as a web service you control) verify that the license is still good periodically.